# How to get php-fpm details in the process list

Tags: linux, php-fpm, process

In my process list with "top" command, I am getting a lot of php-fpm processes.
Is there a possibility to get more info on that porcesses like:

- Who initiated the process (IP)
- Which class is called there
- etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically: No, not the information you're after, not on already running PHP processes.  You *might* get something of use by running strace on one of the running processes (strace -p ), but only in as much as you'll see what system calls it's making, which might allow you to infer further information.  But if it's stuck in a PHP-code loop (not making syscalls), you'll see nothing useful.

Also, it's worth noting that the whole point of php-fpm is to have the processes running permanently, ready to process requests, rather than firing up a php process per CGI request, so simply having a lot of them in the output of 'top' is not necessarily a bad thing.